# "Dynamic" div between 2 "Static" divs [CSS][ASP.NET]

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, class, html

I have some problems with css that I need help with.

I have the following code:

```
<div class="UpperClass"></div>

<div class="LowerClass"></div>
```

Wit the following simple CSS:

```
.UpperClass{
background-color: red;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
}


.MiddleClass{
background-color: green;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
}

.LowerClass{
background-color: blue;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
}
```

Now, in code behind I am dynamically adding the middle class div:

```
int count = 1; //Could be anything

foreach (var item in count)
{
    Label placeholder = new Label();
    StringBuilder sbExample = new StringBuilder();
    sbExample.append("<div class='MiddleClass'></div>");
    HtmlString text = new HtmlString(sbExample.ToString());
    placeholder.Text = text.ToString();
    this.Controls.Add(placeholder);
}
```

Now, all 3 divs are showing on the page, but the div with the middleclass is behind the upperclass, what I want is the upperclass to come first, then all middleclass divs and below that the lowerclass div, all nicely sorted below each other. How do I do that?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

Also, if I want a wrapper around it, how can I place it like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="UpperClass">
    </div>
        //Middle class here
    <div class="LowerClass">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you making sure that you insert your `.MiddleClass` objects in the right place?

Comment: You're not willing to add them all dynamically?

Comment: I have not yet defined a location, because I don't know how I do that. As for now, it just adds a label that contains the div and that label is located in the upper-left corner where .UpperClass is located

Comment: can you put a picture ?

Comment: @bump, the .UpperClass and .LowerClass are always the same, its the .MiddleClass that I want to add dynamically, later on I'll add a list where it will take contents out of it inside the foreach loop.

Comment: You can create a placeholder in between upper and lower and add there.

Comment: @KrishnaDhungana, That does not work, if count is 2 or more, the latest one will be displayed and the others are "forgotten".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the front end have this:

```
<div class="UpperClass"></div>

<%= PopulateMiddleClass() %>

<div class="LowerClass"></div>
```

and on the backend

```
String PopulateMiddleClass()
{
    String ret = "";
    //loop through and populate string
    return ret;
}
```

Or

```
<div class="UpperClass"></div>

<asp:PlaceHolder ID="MyPlaceHolder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>

<div class="LowerClass"></div>
```

Then on the backend

```
Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Literal literal = new Literal();
    literal.Text = "<div class='MiddleClass'></div>";
    MyPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(literal); // you could loop through and keep adding controls or you could compile them all into the one literal.
}
```

Hopefully this gets you on your way.

Comment: Thanks, it works and does exactly what it is supposed to. (I used the second solution)

Answer (score 1):

You can create one div with attribute **runat="server"** and use it as shown below :

**Design Page:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="UpperClass">
    </div>
    <div runat="server" id="divMiddle">
    </div>
    <div class="LowerClass"></div>
</div>
```

**Code Behind :**

```
int count = 1; //Could be anything

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++ )
{
    Label placeholder = new Label();
    StringBuilder sbExample = new StringBuilder();
    sbExample.Append("<div class='MiddleClass'></div>");
    HtmlString text = new HtmlString(sbExample.ToString());
    placeholder.Text = text.ToString();
    this.divMiddle.Controls.Add(placeholder);
}
```